# How to execute os command from mysql5 for windows?

Tags: mysql, linux, windows, shell

In mysql5.X database on Linux the command `system` or `!` can be used to run bash command from database command line.

Are there equivalent commands as `system` or `!` in mysql5.X database for Windows?

Linux:

```
mysql> !ifconig
```

Windows:

```
mysql> !ipconfig
```

The Windows command does not work!

Comment: per [documenation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-commands.html) this "only works in Unix". Welcome to SO. Please fill in the 5.X version for your next question. For pure DB questions use the site https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The mysql 8 command line client supports the system command for windows. Since you can connect to a 5.5 server with it, maybe upgrading just the client is an option? But just to clarify: the command does not run on your database server, it just starts a local (windows) shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In mysql5.X database (for Linux), command "system" or "!" can be used to run bash command from database command Linux.

You misunderstand.

This is not SQL command. This is command-line client command. And it will work only in CLI or another client which supports this command. It will NOT work if you try to send in to MySQL server directly by any technique.

> Is there a equivalent command as "system" or "!" in mysql5.X database (for Windows)?

If used CLI version supports this command then it will work otherwise no. This not depends on MySQL server version.

Answer (score 0):

Windows is not the same operating system, and as such the names of the tools internally are, in many cases, completely different, like `ls` vs. `dir`.

`ipconfig` is a Linux thing but it's also not necessarily a given that it'll be present. On more modern distributions the `ip` command is becoming the default. That's to say you'll need to lookup what the command you're going to run is, and verify that with testing.

You'll need to run the command *appropriate for the environment you're running on*, whatever that is.

That being said, running shell commands inside of the `mysql>` shell is highly irregular and should be a last resort. Doing it can be viewed as **highly suspicious** and may be restricted.